# How to add a user to PostgreSQL from the Ubuntu command line?

Tags: postgresql, shell, ubuntu, postgresql-9.2, createuser

I want to add a user and give the `createdb` permission to it in the PostgreSQL from a Ubuntu command line! I know this can be done by going inside consul and run this:

```
ALTER USER joe CREATEDB
```

But I want to do it from Ubuntu command line!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`createuser`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-createuser.html).
While logged in to your server as the `postgres` OS user:

```sh
createuser --createdb joe
```

Or, if you are some other user with the necessary `sudo` privileges:

```sh
sudo -u postgres createuser --createdb joe
```

Find more command-line options [in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-createuser.html) or with:

```sh
man createuser
```